# What does "unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'list'" means?

Tags: python

I want to know what exactly the above error means even if i have given the data in float.

```
     16 Rbar = 8314.0  # universal gas constant in N.m/kmol.K
     17 T = 513.0      # in kelvin
---> 18 delpbydelT = (Rbar/(vbar-b) + a/[2*vbar*(vbar+b)*T**1.5]*10**5)/10**3  # in kj/(m^3*K)
     19 
     20 # By The Maxwell relation
```

in calculation of `depbydelT`

Comment: You're dividing a number by a list.

Comment: Hint `[1]*3**2` creates and array with 9 elements : `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression:

```
[2*vbar*(vbar+b)*T**1.5]
```

creates a list object with one element. Python then tries to use that list object in a division operation with `a / <outcome of the list object expression>`.

Perhaps you meant to use `(...)` instead to group the expression instead:

```
delpbydelT = (Rbar/(vbar-b) + a/(2*vbar*(vbar+b)*T**1.5)*10**5)/10**3
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that you cannot write `x/y` being `x` a value of type `float` and `y` a value of type `list`.

It happens because in Python the expression `[x]` is actually a list. If you want to nest parenthesis you just them, as many levels as you need:

```
delpbydelT = (Rbar/(vbar-b) + a/(2*vbar*(vbar+b)*T**1.5)*10**5)/10**3
```